# long-pull bar-end brake lever for bullhorn bar

Tags: handlebars, brake-levers

I'm thinking of trying out a bullhorn bar but don't want to spend a lot of money on the experiment.  My brakes require a long-pull lever. Is there such a thing as a long-pull bar-end brake lever?

The bike has mechanical disc brakes that require a long-pull lever.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I've seen. The closest thing I can think of is Paul Component's [Cross Lever](https://www.paulcomp.com/shop/components/brake-levers/inline/cross-lever/), which lets you change its pivot point to change the pull, but it's really not designed for bullhorns.

The alternative is to use a Travel Agent.